# comparator opamps & AND gate

Tags: operational-amplifier, digital-logic, comparator

[image]

I have two comparator opamps which connected AND gate. I would like to change the output of the AND gate by changing the voltage on the 5k resistor with the Potentiometer.

I increased potentiometer value when the voltage at 5k was less than -0.5V. When the value at 5k exceeds -0.5V, AND gate output is high, so the voltage at 5k turned positive.

In this case I increase voltage at 5k above 0.75V by decreasing the value of potentiometer, but the output cannot be negative and it started oscillating.   What could be the reason of that?

**Edit**

I tried to create -1V + 1V on RV2 and R1 with feedback from AND gate output. But since the output of the AND gate is 0-5V, first voltage divider was used to reduce the range to 0-2V. 1V power supply(V3) was used for the -1V + 1V range. V3 for the first test, it will replaced with a voltage substractor circuit.

Comment: The output of U1 and one pin of R10 are connected together. But there's a dot indicating there's something else attached there from off the top of the page. What is it?

Comment: On the full scale image it's clear that there isn't. There's a stray dot on VEE on U2-B as well.

Answer (score 2):

A few pointers:

- Op-amps are not ideal for use as a comparator. A proper comparator is better as they have been designed for the job and won't latch up like some op-amps do.
- The ones you have chosen can only swing to V<sup>+</sup> - 1.5 V. This *might* be OK for your application.
- Your op-amps' outputs can swing to -5 V. I suspect that this will destroy the AND gate.

The whole circuit is very strange as you have a potential divider attached to V3 followed by another potential divider RV2 and R1.

Please edit your question to explain what you are trying to make and we can address further. We'd be interested to know how you're generating V3 too.

Answer (score 1):

The outputs of the two LM358 are going to switch to either +5V **or -5V**. Because that's the power you supplied to them.

- **The 74HC08 cannot accept a negative input voltage.**

It's a logic IC, it handles voltages between 0V and VCC.

Depending on the accuracy of the simulation, the results are random. A real circuit will blow up.

Comment: "*A real circuit will blow up.*", that's a little bit overdramatic as if we're randomly blowing things up like Michael Bay.

Comment: *The white smoke needs to stick in the case.* It's the ghost that makes the magic box run.

Comment: *"A real circuit will blow up"*, that's about the strength of it. Knackered says it too.

Comment: Sorry, English isn't my first language. In German, we say *hochgehen* for *to explode* as well as for climbing the stairs.

Answer (score 0):

If you were to work out the bugs of a circuit like the one pictured above, keep in mind that by introducing feedback with digital circuits, the delays will cause circuits like this to oscillate. Feed back in non clocked digital circuits causes oscillations

Comment: Can you explain what you mean by "like this"? Feedback in digital circuits does not **always** cause oscillation...if it did we wouldn't have latches and flip-flops.

Comment: Didn't think about that, in non clocked circuits